# gorm.DB can't preload field currencies for model.Currency

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

I was looking through `gorm.DB`'s docs and sources but can't seem to understand the purpose of `Preload`.

I thought that is the "preloaded schema/tables/rows" that you can use afterwards" but cannot somehow use it that way.

For instance I have the following `struct`

```golang
package model

type Currency struct {
  ID           uint64 `gorm:"primary_key"`
  CurrencyCode string `gorm:"size:3"`
}
```

but when I do something like this to compare `Find` and `Preload`

```
logger.Info("Preload")
var preloadCurrencies []model.Currency
dbMySQL.Preload("currencies").Find(&preloadCurrencies)
for i, curr := range preloadCurrencies {
    // stuff
}

logger.Info("find")
var currencies []model.Currency
dbMySQL.Find(&currencies)
for i, curr := range currencies {
    // stuff
}
```

I get the following (with ):

```
INFO[0000] Preload
(/go/src/SOMESOURCES/main.go:28)
[2018-01-21 11:08:47]  [1.02ms]  SELECT * FROM `currencies`
[168 rows affected or returned ]
(/go/src/SOMESOURCES/main.go:28)
[2018-01-21 11:08:47]  can't preload field currencies for model.Currency
INFO[0000] find
(/go/src/SOMESOURCES/main.go:37)
[2018-01-21 11:08:47]  [0.90ms]  SELECT * FROM `currencies`
[168 rows affected or returned ]
```

DB schema:

```
show columns from currencies;
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| currency_code | char(3)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The [doc](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#preloading-eager-loading) stated that `Preload` is other name for *eager loading* (the opposite of *lazy loading*). Using `Preload` only make sense for JOIN query, e.g. joining `person` and `occupation`. In this case, you can `Preload` the `occupation` (load all the occupation records) while finding for certain person(s).